# Can't get images to go under each other

Tags: html, image, css

ello I'm new to html and css and tried to display a images that are floating right. Now I want to get the images under each other but is doesn't work. Can someone help me?

this my css code for the images:

```
.imagesLeft{
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
}
.imagesRight{
 float: right;
 margin: 5px;
}
```

this my html code for the images:

```
 <div class="imagesRight">
     <img src="../images/medewerkers.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="imagesRight">
      <img src="../images/medewerkers1.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="imagesRight">
     <img src="../images/medewerkers2.jpg">
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you mean you want the images to stack vertically or do you want the images to be overlapping each other?

Comment: Aside - you don't have to place images inside divs. Setting their display as block and height as well as width will cause them to behave like, let's say, they're divs themselves

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want them to be stacked under each other you can use:

```
.imagesRight{
   float: right;
   margin: 5px;
   clear: right; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating won't get the images stacked.  For that, you'll have to use position:absolute, and top/bottom, left/right positioning.  You can use z-index to change the stack order.

```
.imagesRight {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/J5TDG/) demonstrating it.  As per the comment below, placing a containing div with positioning to it may prevent future headaches.  I've updated my fiddle to include that.

Comment: because Thomas is new to html and css as he mentioned it would be good to point out, that all three divs with images inside should be placed in a relative positioned container. Otherwise, they may mess the layout pretty badly

Comment: Here is the same fiddle that removes the images when clicked on, so you can see what order they are stacked in. http://jsfiddle.net/nightstalker22/J5TDG/3/ If you want to change the order of the stack, use z-index in line style on each image.

Answer (score 0):

Cause your question was not real clear to me what you want with stacking I've created a little example with 3 different possibilities have a look [at the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gF8AX/1/).

the last two examples are probably the interesting ones. the styling looks there liks this:

```
.position-relative {
    background-color:orange;
}
.position-relative img {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
.z-index {
    background-color:gold;
    position:relative;
    margin:20px;
    padding:20px;
}
.z-index img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
        border:2px solid red;
}
.z-index img.first {
    z-index:3;
}
.z-index img.seccond {
    z-index:2;
}
.z-index img.last {
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: also aside: Thomas tagged this question as CSS3 so what for use classes like "first" or "second" if you can use ":first-child", ":nth-child(n)" or ":last-child" selectors?

Comment: @AZ I want it to keep it simple and clear and point out the z-index not the :nth-child() selectors. but now he sees it and can try it

Comment: sure, i'm just bitching around hoping Thomas or sb else would learn sth new about CSS's awesomeness ;)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this fiddle can help you:
u don't have to use `float`  this divs, because it's stacked.
[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kxE24/)